# Java Lambda: Set specific fields via later setters, using a key field in the object

Tags: java, java-stream

I have `List<MyBean>` mostly but not completely populated. Later code needs to set the remaining fields from a DB sub-fetch which is keyed to the original List's `planId` field.

```
List<MyBean> results = service.getPrimaryResults(); // Contains field MyBean.planId populated
// ...
populateAdditionalFields(results);
```

Sub-method with my solution, which looks too complicated and is probably inefficient:

```
public void populateAdditionalFields(List<MyBean> primaryResults) {

     List<Object[]> additionalResults = service.getAdditionResults();

     /* This Service call returns List<Object[]>, as follows:
        [0] : planId
        [1] : reminderHistoryStr
        [2] : specialStr
        etc.
       These are the remaining field that need to be populated
     */

     additionalResults.stream().forEach(obj -> {
               // Find PrimaryResult with this PlanID, in obj[0] 
               Optional<MyBean> primaryResult = 
                   primaryResults.stream().filter(x -> x.getPlanId().equals(obj[0])).findFirst();
               // Now set other fields with this PlanID
               if (primaryResult.isPresent()) {
                    primaryResult.get().setReminderHistory((String)obj[1]);
                    primaryResult.get().setSpecialStr((String)obj[2]);
                    // etc.
               }
            });
```

This seems inefficient, I'm doing nested `stream()`s.

Is there an efficient solution to set the remaining fields from one collection to another where there is a match on the key field?

Comment: `additionalResults.stream().forEach`
You don't need stream here `forEach` is enough imho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a map of the primary results (planId as key), so later you can fetch it on o(1) when looping over additionalResults.

```
Map<String,MyBean> resultsMap = primaryResults.stream()
                                              .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                                 MyBean::getPlanId,
                                                 Function.identity()));
additionalResults.stream().forEach(obj -> {
               // Find PrimaryResult with this PlanID, in obj[0] 
               Optional<MyBean> primaryResult = Optional.ofNullable(resultsMap.get(obj[0]));
               // Now set other fields with this PlanID
               if (primaryResult.isPresent()) {
                    primaryResult.get().setReminderHistory((String)obj[1]);
                    primaryResult.get().setSpecialStr((String)obj[2]);
                    // etc.
               }
            });
```